# Saving Group of Persons and every change in it

Tags: database-design

I have this situation were I need to include Persons inside a Group.
For that, I create a relation like the one showed in the image.

[table diagram http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/6076/imagetkr.png](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/6076/imagetkr.png)

The groups are constantly changing (several times a day, several persons are added and removed from a group).
I need to save the status of the group everytime it changes (which persons were in it and between which dates), for later analysis.

For that, everytime a Person is to be added or removed from a Group, my application does the following:

1. get the current Group (and the Persons in it)
2. create a list (in memory) of Persons in the group, excluding or adding the ones to bem removed or added
3. update the EndDate on the current group
4. creates a new Group
5. insert the Persons (from the list in point 2) in the Group
6. return the new GroupId

This GroupId is used to save a log of the changes in the group.

An example of the data generated after some movements:

```
PERSON:
PersonId   Name
 1         John
 2         Sally
 3         Pete
```

-Adding John:

```
GROUP:
GroupId   Description   StartDate            EndDate
 1        John added    31/7/2009 11:00:00   null

GROUPPERSON:
GroupPersonId   GroupId   PersonId
 1               1         1
```

-Adding Sally:

```
GROUP:
GroupId   Description   StartDate            EndDate
 1        John added    31/7/2009 11:00:00   31/7/2009 11:35:00
 2        Sally added   31/7/2009 11:35:00   null

GROUPPERSON:
GroupPersonId   GroupId   PersonId
 1               1         1
 2               2         1
 3               2         2
```

-Adding Pete:

```
GROUP:
GroupId   Description   StartDate            EndDate
 1        John added    31/7/2009 11:00:00   31/7/2009 11:35:00
 2        Sally added   31/7/2009 11:35:00   31/7/2009 12:10:00
 3        Pete added    31/7/2009 12:10:00   null

GROUPPERSON:
GroupPersonId   GroupId   PersonId
 1               1         1
 2               2         1
 3               2         2
 4               3         1
 5               3         2
 6               3         3
```

-Remove John:

```
GROUP:
GroupId   Description   StartDate            EndDate
 1        John added    31/7/2009 11:00:00   31/7/2009 11:35:00
 2        Sally added   31/7/2009 11:35:00   31/7/2009 12:10:00
 3        Pete added    31/7/2009 12:10:00   31/7/2009 12:24:00
 4        John removed  31/7/2009 12:24:00   null

GROUPPERSON:
GroupPersonId   GroupId   PersonId
 1               1         1
 2               2         1
 3               2         2
 4               3         1
 5               3         2
 6               3         3
 7               4         2
 8               4         3
```

This is the design I came up with, but as I'm a single developer I'm afraid I'm not seeing it clearly.
Can you point me other (better) ways of achieving the same features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me how you know that group 2 is the "same" group as group 1 - or is that information not important?  Here is another solution, assuming groups continue to exist even when new members are added (which seems reasonable!)

```
create table groups (groupId integer primary key);
create table persons (personId integer primary key)
create table group_member (groupId references groups,
                           personId references persons,
                           startDate date,
                           endDate date);
```

Adding John:

```
insert into group_members (groupId, personId, startDate)
values (1, 1, '1/7/2009 11:00:00');
```

Removing John:

```
update group_members 
set endDate = '31/7/2009 12:24:00'
where groupId = 1 and personId = 1;
```

So by the end of your example you have:

```
PERSON:
PersonId   Name
 1         John
 2         Sally
 3         Pete

GROUP
groupId
1

GROUP_MEMBERS:
groupId personId startDate          endDate
1       1        1/7/2009 11:00:00  31/7/2009 12:24:00
1       2        31/7/2009 11:35:00
1       3        31/7/2009 12:10:00
```

To find out the membership of group 1 at some given date and time:

```
select personId
from   group_members
where  groupId = 1
and    startDate <= :given_datetime
and    (endDate is null or endDate >= :given_datetime);
```

Comment: To know which group is the one I want, I save the current group Id to another location, so before creating the new group, I check what's the current and the replace it. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the incomplete information you provide, it looks like you should keep a Movements table:

```
Date/Time           Group      Action    Person    // The Universe

17/7/2009 10:01:00  Group A    Enter     John      // {A: John}
17/7/2009 10:02:00  Group A    Enter     Sally     // {A: John, Sally}
17/7/2009 11:22:23  Group B    Enter     Pete      // {A: John, Sally}, {B: Pete}
17/7/2009 11:34:45  Group A    Exit      John      // {A: Sally}, {B: Pete}
```

Note that the universe can be calculated just from the movements table. (Of course as the table grows this calculation becomes more costly, but I'm just making a basic suggestion.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added some more information to explain my implementation.